# How to declare new javascript object type only if it not declared yet

Tags: javascript, class

I need a Set object type in my code. But in some browsers such object type [already exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn251547%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) and my class and standard are compatible by members. How I can declare my class only if it not exists in browser script host ?

For example:

```
if (typeof Set === 'undefined' ) {
      function Set() {
          // object initialization code ...
      }
}
```

It's not works because internal Set function object is not global.

Comment: Unless you're adding functionality to browser that miss it, I would not create an object which sort of already exists

Answer (score 1):

The most robust way is probably to use this:

```
if (!("Set" in window))
{
    window.Set = function ()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the chance that `window.Set` is defined, but its value is `undefined`, this will correctly see that it has been defined, unlike checking the value, or using `typeof`.

If you need to run in a situation where `window` is not the global object, you can insert this line at the very top of your script:

```
var global = this;
```

Then you can use `global` instead of `window`.

Comment: How to define global object in "if" statement ?

Comment: Can you write sample for Windows Script Host (not for browser, that is window object is not exists)?

Comment: thanks, you code works good!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
if (window.Set === undefined) {
    window.Set = MySet;
}
```

Comment: How to do it if my code works not in browser? For example in Windows Script Host ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to determine whether it is `undefined`:

```
if (typeof window.Set === 'undefined')
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple truthiness test will suffice:

```
if (!window.Set) {
    window.Set = ...
```